# Encoding italian quotation marks

Tags: punctuation, input-encodings

I've noticed that using

```
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
```

my quotation marks are ignored. I've used `"` in my source files and i would like to see the same glyph(?) in my output file.

I saw i should use `latin1` instead of `utf8` but this create another problem: my files are encoded in UTF-8 and i can't understand how to convert them to ISO-8859 in Windows.

I would like to receive suggestions on how to solve this without going through my text to change hundreds of quotation marks.

Comment: Quotes should never be input with `"`, but rather with `\`\`` for the opening quotes and `''` for the closing ones.

Comment: that's the problem, in italian there are no opening and closing quotes, otherwise it would be easier.

Comment: If you want to use guillemets, then `<<` and `>>` work if you say `\usepackage[T1]{inputenc}`

Comment: those does not exist in italian too...

Comment: @Chobeat are you sure that there is no difference between opening and closing quotation marks? Because on wikipedia it looks like they do exist http://it.wikipedia.org/wiki/Virgolette.

Comment: @Chobeat I’m Italian and I use quotes all the time: there are different forms for opening and closing. One can choose between “English quotes” or «French quotes», as long as the usage is consistent, but the "straight quotes" are definitely wrong in fine quality printing.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Are you using babel with shorthands? Also a minimum working example would help ...

Added:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[italian]{babel}
\begin{document}
\shorthandoff{"}    

    "

\end{document}
```

works. See the babel documentation.

If you actually want to show a "neutral" quote glyph, you could try something along these lines:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[italian]{babel}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\begin{document}
\shorthandon{"} 
\def"{\textquotedbl}
"i".
\end{document}
```

Beware: this is a horrible thing to do, and it may break other parts of your document.

Comment: i'm using \usepackage[italian]{babel}

Comment: i know it's horrible but for now it's the best solution. Anyway "\def"{\textquotedbl}" doesn't work. I think i can understand what it does, but i can't find out why it doesn't work.

Comment: @Chobeat: you need to compile the whole thing for this answer to work, not just the 6th line. Specifically, you need to load `fontenc`.

Comment: solved, i had to switch \shorthandon with \def

Comment: @Chobeat: Are you compiling the above **document**, as shown?

Answer (score 7):

In the `babel` package with "italian" as the language setting, you can use the shortcuts `"<` and `">` to produce left-hand and right-hand guillemets. If you're not happy with the look of the resulting guillemets, you could use the `\enquote{...}` command of the `csquotes` package to produce guillemets that are slightly more curved (relative to what's produced by the `babel` method) and are also spaced slightly further apart.

The two guillemet forms are produced in the MWE below.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[italian]{babel}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[autostyle]{csquotes}
\begin{document}
"<Buona sera, signorina">        \qquad \,via babel's \verb|"<| \ldots \verb|">|

\enquote{Buona sera, signorina}  \qquad via \verb|\enquote{...}|
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: To whoever downvoted this answer: I'd appreciate if you'd leave a comment as to what you disagree with or otherwise find deficient. If you downvoted the answer by accident and would like to reverse this action, please feel free to do so. Thanks in advance.

Comment: It's quite strange that this answer, which is correct, got a downvote.

Comment: @egreg: The downvote doesn't need to be intended. I downvoted you by accident two days ago when I was looking at tex.stackexchange on my smartphone. I would never have realized it if I hadn't got a badge for it (after which I could undo it).